# How can I test my multiplayer game in the same computer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, onpause

The game created in unity but I cannot test the  game. How can I open the game 10 times in the same computer? I also tried `run in Background`. But It works only with two players. I need to test more than with 8 players.

Comment: What environment are you running it in? Is it a release build or debug build? Have you got any friends that can run it?

Comment: What stops you from opening multiple instances of your game?

Comment: @David Yes I tried. But it's paused . I meant I can play  which I opened last time. The others has paused

Comment: Just build up executable and start it on the same machine few times or use virtual machines ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit/ Proyect Settings / Player and check in this inspector panel the option "Run in background"

Comment: you set this in options or programatically?

Comment: the option to get running in background is this. If not work for you, you need to check log looking for any error in another place.

Comment: it works but as said it cannot be possible to test more than 2 players